# Google appengine. How to redirect inside handler constructor

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I have simple handler class:

```
class my_handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(my_handler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.redirect("/")
```

but redirrect doesn't work. What is the bast way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override `dispatch` instead, and redirect instead of calling `super()`.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe

```
self.redirect('/')
```

and if you want immediate without execution of script (without adding return)

```
self.redirect('/', abort=True)
```

Read more at the webapp2 docs about [redirect](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.redirect)

Answer (score 0):

The way to get a redirect to happen is to call `redirect` from `get` (or `post`, if that's what you need).

Comment: redirecting from GET to Post in the same handler wouldn't be simpler in logic to do `def get(self): self.post()` for simplicity?